# Highlight next <li> at a specific day and time

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have an unordered list set-up in my HTML. Starting with the first li, every Sunday at 7:00am I'd like to highlight the next li for the week, then cycle through the list, highlighting each li for a week at a time.

I've written the following javascript code which cycles through the list items at 1000ms intervals.

```
$(function() {
    $('ul li:first').addClass('active');

    setInterval(function () {
      var date = new Date();
      if (date.getDay() === 0 &amp;&amp; date.getHours() === 7 &amp;&amp; date.getMinutes === 0 &amp;&amp; date.getSeconds == 0) {
        transition();
      }
    }, 1000);

  });

  function transition() {
      var current = $('.active');
      var next = null;
      if (current.next('li').size() == 0) {
          next = $('ul li:first');
      } else {
          next = current.next('li');
      }
      current.removeClass('active');
      next.addClass('active');
  };
```

What I can't figure out is how to "pause" the loop on each li for an interval of a week. Would I just change the 1000ms interval to however many ms are in a week?

Comment: Is the lifetime of your page really over a week?

Comment: You missed parenthesis on the line around `transition` correct syntax is  : `transition();`.

Comment: @Zeratops Dang! He's gonna have to wait until next week I guess.

Comment: Basically, I just want to run the transition function every Sunday at 7:00am, highlighting the next li following the li that was highlighted the week before.

Answer (score 1):

Don't know why you'd ever want to set a transition so infrequently. Seems like a lot of code to write so that if someone happens to be on your page just before seven, The calendar will transition to the next week.

Technically, your implementation should work, but it has to run a piece of code every second. You can set a timeout for specifically at 7am on Sunday if you construct the date and do some date math, and then set a timeout that recursively calls itself to do it every week. In case your user is on your page for more than one Sunday...

```js
$(function() {
      $('ul li:first').addClass('active');

      function queueTransitionForNextWeek() {
        var now = new Date();

        function nextSundayAtSeven(date) {
          var clone = new Date(date.getTime());
          clone.setDate(clone.getDate() - clone.getDay() + 7);
          clone.setHours(7);
          clone.setMinutes(0);
          return clone;
        }
        var msTillNextWeek = nextSundayAtSeven(now) - now;

        setTimeout(function() {
          transition();
          queueTransitionForNextWeek();
        }, msTillNextWeek);
      }

      queueTransitionForNextWeek();

      function transition() {
        var current = $('.active');
        var next = null;
        if (current.next('li').size() == 0) {
          next = $('ul li:first');
        } else {
          next = current.next('li');
        }
        current.removeClass('active');
        next.addClass('active');
      };
```